# Export ROS_MASTER_URI error in win_ros

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, win-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am getting a little bit crazy with his problem. I installed [win_ros hydro](http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros) in windows 7, and I am trying to run a simple talker from a **Visual studio 2012 professional** project. I followed the instructions, but I always get an exception saying that ROS_MASTER_URI is not defined in my enviroment. I saw that this issue was already solved in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975715/rosinit-throws-an-error-windows-roscpp), by defining the `ROS_MASTER_URI` in the debug enviroment. However, I tried this a hundred times, adding different lines:

`ROS_MASTER_URI = http://localhost:11311`

`ROS_MASTER_URI = http://127.0.0.1:11311`

`ROS_MASTER_URI = http://andres-PC:11311`

nothing works. I also tried with **VS2010 professional**, but nothing. Could it be the version of the VS?. The exception always appears with the ROS_MASTER_URI undefined. It must be some stupid thing that I am missing, and I am not able to fix. I have to mention that I didn't defined the ROS_MASTER_URI globally in my system, due to I don't know how on windows. In the tutorial of win_ros, the hyperlink to explain how to do this is broken.

I cannot find more information about this problem, so any experienced help will be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249029/export-ros_master_uri-error-in-win_ros/) by [anflores](https://answers.ros.org/users/28615/anflores/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2016-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anflores](https://answers.ros.org/users/28615/anflores/) on 2016-12-01**:
Any help please? It is related with the enviroment variables in windows, that I guess I am not defining them properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure this is actually the solution to your problem, but the general procedure to add/remove/edit environment variables on Windows 7 is:

1. From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
2. Choose `Properties` from the context menu.
3. Click the `Advanced system settings` link.
4. Click `Environment Variables`
5. In the `Edit System Variable` (or `New System Variable`) window, specify the value of the environment variable.
6. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.

If you have a restricted user account (or anything not with administrator level access), you might not be able to do this. For those accounts, go to the *User Accounts* applet in the Control Panel, and click the *Change my environment variables* link at the bottom of the list in the left side of the window (see [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/windows-7-set-environment-variable-without-admin-access/) link fi).

To avoid issues with DNS, use only IPs when setting `ROS_MASTER_URI`. If you intend to have your Windows ROS nodes communicate with other machines, I'd also set `ROS_IP` to the IP of the Windows machine.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anflores](https://answers.ros.org/users/28615/anflores/) on 2016-12-02**:
Hi! thank you for your answer. The thing is that I tried your proposal, adding the `ROS_MASTER_URI` to the enviroment variable, but it didn't work. I think I have to define it in the Visual Studio enviroment variable while debugging, but I tried many times and I still get the error. I don't know...

**Comment by [anflores](https://answers.ros.org/users/28615/anflores/) on 2016-12-02**:
Hey, I just discovered that I worked!! I just defined a new enviroment variable `ROS_URI_MASTER` with value http://andres-PC:11311. Thank you very much! I was really stacked

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-03**:
I assume you mean `ROS_MASTER_URI`, right? Also: if you have any other PCs in your ROS netwerk, using IPs might be more robust.